# How to use bash and curl with escaped json?

Tags: json, bash, curl, elasticsearch, escaping

The two commands below work perfectly outside of a script if I execute them one after the other, however, if I put them inside a bash script. They fail.

```
DATA="{\"size\":500,\"sort\":{\"@timestamp\":\"desc\"},\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"analyze_wildcard\":true,\"query\":\"tx.traceId: AIP1447283489-6 AND event: published_notification AND attempt: 1\"}},\"filter\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"range\":{\"@timestamp\":{\"gte\":1420099200000,\"lte\":1451635199999}}}],\"must_not\":[]}}}},\"highlight\":{\"pre_tags\":[\"@kibana-highlighted-field@\"],\"post_tags\":[\"@\/kibana-highlighted-field@\"],\"fields\":{\"*\":{}}},\"aggs\":{\"2\":{\"date_histogram\":{\"field\":\"@timestamp\",\"interval\":\"1w\",\"pre_zone\":\"-08:00\",\"pre_zone_adjust_large_interval\":true,\"min_doc_count\":0,\"extended_bounds\":{\"min\":1420099200000,\"max\":1451635199999}}}},\"fields\":[\"*\",\"_source\"],\"script_fields\":{},\"fielddata_fields\":[\"log.timestamp\",\"@timestamp\",\"val\"]}"

curl -s -XPOST http://username:password@url/elasticsearch/index-*/_search -d $DATA | jq '.hits.hits[0].fields."log.timestamp"[0]'
```

By using set -x I've found that the final curl command that is executed is:

```
curl -s -XPOST 'http://username:password@url/elasticsearch/index-*/_search' -d '{"size":500,"sort":{"@timestamp":"desc"},"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"query_string":{"analyze_wildcard":true,"query":"tx.traceId:' AIP1447283489-6 AND event: published_notification AND attempt: '1"}},"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"@timestamp":{"gte":1420099200000,"lte":1451635199999}}}],"must_not":[]}}}},"highlight":{"pre_tags":["@kibana-highlighted-field@"],"post_tags":["@\/kibana-highlighted-field@"],"fields":{"*":{}}},"aggs":{"2":{"date_histogram":{"field":"@timestamp","interval":"1w","pre_zone":"-08:00","pre_zone_adjust_large_interval":true,"min_doc_count":0,"extended_bounds":{"min":1420099200000,"max":1451635199999}}}},"fields":["*","_source"],"script_fields":{},"fielddata_fields":["log.timestamp","@timestamp","val"]}'
```

And if you notice there are extra single quotes like so: ' added around the value of "query". As you can see here:

```
"query":"tx.traceId:' AIP1447283489-6 AND event: published_notification AND attempt: '1"
```

What the heck is going on and how do I use these two commands with this json in a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't quote `$DATA` in your command

```
curl -s -XPOST http://username:password@url/elasticsearch/index-*/_search -d $DATA
```

so `$DATA` is subject to word splitting (and more) after parameter expansion is performed. Your `$DATA` contains whitespace in the value of `query`, so it's split there and broken into multiple arguments. What you want is

```
curl -s -XPOST http://username:password@url/elasticsearch/index-*/_search -d "$DATA"
```

Also, my personal advice is to quote JSON string with single quotes, and use `'\''` when you need a literal single quote. Quoting JSON with double quotes in shell just makes the result impossible to read...

Comment: Also, I'm not sure about your claim "the two commands below work perfectly outside of a script if I execute them one after the other". You should have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier to read from a here document than to ensure you've quoted all the quotation marks properly.

```
url='http://username:password@url/elasticsearch/index-*/_search'
curl -s -X POST "$url" -d@- <<EOF | jq '.hits.hits[0].fields."log.timestamp"[0]'
{ "size":500,
  "sort": {
     ...
}
EOF
```